# Could not execute ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`state1` RENAME TO `state`;No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to rename the tables that I have
So my query code is simply

```html
function renameTable($db ,$tb , $newtb){
        $query = "ALTER TABLE `$db`.`$tb` RENAME TO `$newtb`;";


        if (mysqli_query($this->link, $query)) {
            echo "Table renamed Successfully";
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not execute $query" . mysqli_error($this->link);
        }
        
        
    }
```

and my PHP file contains

```
<?php foreach ($alltables as $tablevalues) : ?>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:63342/Ass2/pages/tables.php?db=<?php echo $table->setdb('db') ?>&table=<?php echo $table->setdb('table') ?>">

<?php if(isset($_POST["editdb" . $tablevalues])): ?>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">

            <input type="text" name="newtbname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new name" aria-label="Recipient's username" >
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" >edit</button>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="<?php echo "editdb" . $tablevalues?>">
    <i class="fas fa-edit" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
</button>

<?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['newtbname'])){

                $table->renameTable($table->setdb('db') , $table->setdb('table') , $_POST['newtbname']);
            } ?>
        </form>
```

The setdb function just gets the query from the URL and the connection works since I have used it my other functions.

The idea is to get the db and table from the query and rename it.
But I get NO DATABASE SELECTED.
Any idea where I might be wrong?

Connection block:

```
class dbConnection{

protected $db_conn;
public $db_user = 'root';
public $db_pass = '';
public $db_host = 'localhost';

function connect(){
    try {

        $this->db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

        return $this->db_conn;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Table.php

```
<?PHP
class ManageTable {

public $link;

function __construct(){
    $dbConnection = new dbConnection();
    $this->link = $dbConnection->connect();
}

function setdb($q){

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')
        $url = "https://";
    else
        $url = "http://";
    // Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL.
    $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    // Append the requested resource location to the URL
    $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $url_components = parse_url($url);

    parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
    return $params[$q];

}
```

Comment: Post full code. renameTable($table->setdb('db')..... Why do you set data rather than passing the data to fn

Comment: I dont set it the setdb just gets the result from the URL. So if i have localhost:: .....?db=whatever I want to get that whatever from the url

Comment: Please paste mysql connection code block

Comment: Added the block

Answer (score 1):

As error says You have not selected the db.

Change it

```
 $this->db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

to

```
 $this->db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'YourDbNameHere');
```

And you are not using PDO, then why PDO Exceptions is used ?